# Does performing Database Operations in MainActivity freezes UI?

Tags: android, user-interface, android-asynctask, android-sqlite

I'm developing an app to track vehicles and calculate distance traveled by them. I have a device fitted on vehicles which sends `LatLngs` to my mobile via SMS. My app stores the SMS containing `LatLng` in `SQLiteDatabase`. My table has one Latitude and Longitude per row. Day by day the number of rows in my table grows huge.
When I retrieve those data from table to draw map and Calculate distance my app freezes for a mere second between each time I tried to access data from table. How to make it faster? Any suggestions please.

```
    public void calculateDistance(String date) {
    googleMap.clear();
    double cumulativeDistance = 0;
    String selectLog1="select rowid _id,* from logTable where date='"+date+"' and deviceNo='"+deviceNo+"'";
    Cursor cursor4=db.rawQuery(selectLog1,null);
    if(cursor4.getCount()>2) {
        while (cursor4.moveToNext()) {
            String strLatLng = cursor4.getString(cursor4.getColumnIndex("log"));
            strDate11=cursor4.getString(cursor4.getColumnIndex("date"));
            String[] strArray = strLatLng.split(",");
            latitude2 = Double.parseDouble(strArray[0]);
            longitude2 = Double.parseDouble(strArray[1]);
            time11=strArray[2];
            coordList1.add(new LatLng(latitude2, longitude2));
            timeList.add(strLatLng+","+time11);
        }

        BitmapDescriptor bitmapDescriptor = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ledorange);
        for (String strData:timeList){
            String[] strDatas=strData.split(",");
            double latData=Double.parseDouble(strDatas[0]);
            double lngData=Double.parseDouble(strDatas[1]);
            String timeAt=strDatas[2];
            googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latData,lngData)).title(vehicleName).icon(bitmapDescriptor).snippet("Known @ " + timeAt + "," + strDate11));
        }

        timeList.removeAll(timeList);

        CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(latitude2, longitude2), 12.5f);
        googleMap.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);
        googleMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions().addAll(coordList1).width(10).color(getResources().getColor(R.color.myBlue)));

        DecimalFormat format = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < (coordList1.size() - 1); i++) {
            LatLng l1 = coordList1.get(i);
            double lat1 = l1.latitude;
            double lng1 = l1.longitude;
            Location location1 = new Location("");
            location1.setLatitude(lat1);
            location1.setLongitude(lng1);

            LatLng l2 = coordList1.get(i + 1);
            double lat2 = l2.latitude;
            double lng2 = l2.longitude;
            Location location2 = new Location("");
            location2.setLatitude(lat2);
            location2.setLongitude(lng2);

            format = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
            double distance = location1.distanceTo(location2) / 1000;
            cumulativeDistance = cumulativeDistance + distance;
        }
        if (preferences.contains("errorRatio")) {
            cumulativeDistance =cumulativeDistance + (cumulativeDistance / 100) * preferences.getInt("errorRatio", 0);
        }
        tvDistance.setText(format.format(cumulativeDistance) + " Km's");
        coordList1.removeAll(coordList1);
    }else {
        tvDistance.setText("No Data");
    }
}
```

Comment: `Indexing` your search and join columns is your friend. And `AsyncTask` as well.

Answer (score 0):

If your queries are pretty sizeable, it could freeze up your main thread.

If I were you I would use an `AsyncTask` for your read/write operation, since this would happen on another thread and not freeze up your main thread.

Answer (score 0):

Database operations run on the UI thread unless you tell it otherwise. You can run in a background thread using [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html), like below:

```
private class MyLongTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
     protected void doInBackground(Void... params) {

         // TODO Perform database operations

         return null;
     }

     protected void onPostExecute(Void... params) {
         // TODO update UI with db results
     }
 }
```

You can also use [StrictMode](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/StrictMode.html) to detect network/IO on the main thread, and notify you with either a log message or exception.

Comment: If you call .execute() it will perform the main operations on a background thread, then call onPostExecute() in the UI thread.